# Javascript calculator issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have to following code:

```
<div class="overall">
  <div class="calccont">
    <input type="text" class="output">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="3">3</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="4">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
    var allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    for ( i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++ ) {
    allBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".output").value += allBtns[i].getAttribute("value");
  });
}
```

Im trying to build a calculator in JS and the expected result was putting all the buttons value in the input, but it doesnt seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add your code as a snippet or a jsfiddle so we can test it live?

Comment: Sure https://jsfiddle.net/y9yhkxae/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gaus06techian/9dL1zgd8/ -- check this

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `this` to access the current button within your click event:

```js
var allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for (i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++) {
  allBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".output").value += this.getAttribute("value");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="overall">
  <div class="calccont">
    <input type="text" class="output">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="3">3</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="4">4</button>
    <div>
```

Comment: I have also tried with .this. Its wierd that it works in the code snipet, and not in my browser.

Comment: @TudorApostol if the above snippet is not working for you, then there might be something else that causes the problem with your code. Mind the `<div class="overall">` at the very top of your HTML, it is missing a `<`.

Comment: You need to ensure that the script is run _after_ your elements have been created. If you move your script to the end of your page (just before `</body>` does it work?

Comment: Also, I don't know if that was a typo in your comment, but it should be `this` _not_ `.this` (no period).

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark this as answered if it solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `this` keyword to access the clicked button and then get its `value` like this:

```js
var allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for ( i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++ ) {
 allBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".output").value += this.getAttribute("value");
 });
}
```

```html
<div class="overall">
<div class="calccont">
  <input type="text" class="output">
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn" type="button" value="1">1</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" value="2">2</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" value="3">3</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" value="4">4</button>
<div>
```

More about the `this` keyword:

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind
>   method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's
>   called, and ECMAScript 2015 introduced arrow functions whose this is
>   lexically scoped (it is set to the this value of the enclosing
>   execution context).

**On a side note:** You are missing a `<` in the first `div` tag in the code you have posted, that might also be causing you some issues if that wasn't a copy-paste omission.